# Windows Server 2008 R2 VBScript script engine missing

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vbscript, windows

On Win2008R2 x64 I get

```
Input Error: There is no script engine for file extension ".vbs".
```

when starting a `.vbs` file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of possible solutions from [this blog](http://kiranpatils.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension-vbs/):

Open a command prompt and type (make sure you have admin privileges in the console):

```
regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\vbscript.dll
```

Or if that doesn't work.

> 1. Locate the file %windir%\inf\wsh.inf (inf is a hidden
>      folder)
> 2. right click and select “Install”.

Comment: regsvr32 doesn't help
and in my inf folder there is NO `wsh.inf` between `wsdscdrv.inf` and `wstorflt.inf`, ... on the whole system there is no `wsh.inf`

Answer (score 1):

You can register a default scripting host:

`cscript.exe //H:WScript`

You may also want to try adding these registry keys:

http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/105/1/File-association-fixes-for-Windows-Vista.html
or http://www.nilpo.com/2009/07/windows-xp/error-there-is-no-script-engine-for-file-extension/

But I believe the .REG files provided are the same

Answer (score 0):

try installing WSH 5.6 and let me know how it works.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C717D943-7E4B-4622-86EB-95A22B832CAA&displaylang=en

Answer (score -1):

the HKR\Vbscript registry entry was missing on mine

previous entry worked
https://serverfault.com/a/100630/402397